# C++ NetBeans generated header

Tags: c++, netbeans, header-files

I created a class named `view` and NetBeans generated a constructor and a destructor. It also generated a method that takes parameters. I'm not sure what the method that takes parameters is or why it was generated. Can someone tell me what this line of code is:

```
class View {
public:
    View();
    View(const View& orig);          //what is this line?
    virtual ~View();
private:
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and check out the classes section

Comment: Copy constructor. And I don't think autogenerating these functions is a good idea -  netbeans certainly is not a great C++ IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read up on copy constructors and switch to Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a **copy constructor**

A **copy constructor** is a member function which initializes an object using another object of the same class.
And a copy constructor can access private members too of the passed object.

for example:

```
class View
{
private:
    int var1, var2;
public:
    View(int var1, int var2) { this->var1 = var1; this->var2 = var2; } 

    // Copy constructor
    View(const View &orig) {this->var1 = orig.var1; y = orig.var2; }  //Note we are accessing private members of orig

    int getvar1()            {  return var1; }
    int getvar2()            {  return var2; }
};
```

in main:

```
int main()
{
    View v1(10, 15); // Normal constructor is called here
    View v2 = v1; // Copy constructor is called here

    // Let us access values assigned by constructors
    cout << "v1.var1 = " << v1.getvar1() << ", v1.var2 = " << v1.getvar2();
    cout << "\nv2.var1 = " << v2.getvar1() << ", v2.var2 = " << v2.getvar2();
    return 0;
}
```

You will see that the members of v1 and v2 have same values assigned.

In most IDEs, **copy constructor** is "written" in "background" even if you don't write it. That means that you can assign one object to another of the same class type without writing **copy constructor** in class declaration.